# Remove a file shared with me using Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

When right click a file under the "Shared with me" node on Google Drive a context menu item called "Remove" is available to remove the selected item that is shared with me.

Is there a way to achieve the same using Google Drive SDK? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The proposed solution works when the "Shared with" user is a Writer. It won't work when the "Shared with" user is a Reader. I was looking for a way for both Reader and Writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drive V3 - With shared with me the user has a permissions record for the file.  If you remove that then the file will no longer be shared with the user.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the API currently doesn't support this operation. Please file a feature request here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request&labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Drive

Comment: Thanks the info. What's the case in 2019?